# puppettop? How can I see what puppet is doing?

Tags: monitoring, puppet

I'm getting started with Puppet. I added some lines to a manifest and when running Puppet now it's been at 100% cpu for a very longtime. Is there a good way to see what puppet is actually doing? `puppettop`?

`top` gives me this, which is quite useless:

```
top - 20:02:11 up 1 day,  2:30,  5 users,  load average: 1.02, 1.12, 0.93
Tasks: 164 total,   2 running, 162 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 12.5%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 87.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32809072k total, 10412396k used, 22396676k free,   243832k buffers
Swap: 16768892k total,        0k used, 16768892k free,  6978500k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 9761 root      20   0  646m 558m 3568 R  100  1.7  20:42.88 puppet
10509 guaka     20   0 17344 1352  972 R    0  0.0   0:00.28 top
    1 root      20   0 24216 2192 1344 S    0  0.0   0:00.85 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:02.83 ksoftirqd/0
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0
    5 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
```

Comment: What puppet does is run other programs, so doing just `top` should give you a clue to what program Puppet could possibly be running that is eating up CPU.

Comment: How about doing `puppet apply manifest.pp --debug` and seeing what happens?